# Hyperlink in Post entity's textfield

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm creating a Post entity (Activity feed entity) within my custom C# code and I need to be able to add a hyperlink into its text field.

Creating a post entity

```
Entity post = new Entity();
post.LogicalName = "post";
```

I could simply write something like

```
post["text"] = "http://www.google.com"
```

and it would work as a hyperlink. I think there's jQuery (out of a box?) that handles formatting in that case.

But in my case I'd like to add a hyperlink with a custom title. Something similar to

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click</a>
```

Is there a supported way to do this or do I need to write my own client side script for formatting purposes?

Comment: did you try already with the html code or not?

Comment: I tried and it handles it as a normal string. You can play with quotes and single quotes but I wasn't able to get it right that way either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your text box content to work as a hyperlink, the `Format` of the `Textbox` needs to be `URL`. If you can set the format of your textbox, then any text that you put in there ,provided it follows the rules of hyperlink, it will be displayed as one.

Are you creating the attribute, or is it an existing one that you're trying to fiddle with? If it's an existing one, you need to write your own javascript to render it on the form as a hyperlink; and this would be unsupported.

Comment: Yes I'm using existing attribute ("text" attribute) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547434.aspx#bkmk_attributes Right now my code creates a hyperlink and it works, but it is so long than it's not very user friendly. I was hoping that I could give it a title (for example "Click here") or something. But yeah I was a bit worried about that it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hyperlink with custom title like this:

```
string link = "<a onclick='window.open(" + "http://localhost:49944/Default.aspx?     surveyresponseid=" + SurveyResponseId.ToString() + "); ' href='" + "http://localhost:49944/Default.aspx?surveyresponseid=" + SurveyResponseId.ToString() + "' target='_blank' >click this</a>";


post["text"] = link;
```